# Why downvote an already accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, accepted-answer

Earlier today, I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200594/fix-the-order-of-strings-that-have-both-letter-and-number-component/23200695#23200695).  The series of events that followed are

1. The answer was accepted
2. Someone downvoted my accepted answer
3. I commented, asking for an explanation for the downvote
4. The user that accepted my answer then unaccepted it

As of right now, no answer has been accepted.

I am confident that my answer is efficient and correct.  It shows the original poster how to get both of the results that are desired.  However,  I also think that my comment (or the downvote itself) may have made the poster uncomfortable in believing my answer is valid.

What would prompt someone to downvote an already accepted answer?

If the given answer has obviously solved the poster's problem, what does it matter if the other users think it's not a useful answer?  Answers should be specific to each post, should they not?

Comment: The most obvious answer is, "because it's incorrect". Perhaps someone felt - rightly or wrongly, I can't judge - that it's incorrect or doesn't answer the question? I've seen many bad accepted answers in my time

Comment: Agreed.  But I am confident that the answer is efficient and correct.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, I'd just wait - an upvote is bound to even out the downvote eventually.

Comment: Acceptance is merely one person's view of the quality of an answer, and that person is generally not particularly expert in the issue, because they needed to ask the question. Downvoting an accepted answer is no different from downvoting an answer with an existing upvote. That said, it would be more helpful to explain why.

Comment: I'm not sure but I've seen some less-than-sportsman-like behavior on answers sometimes where 2 answers are close... if the "other" answerer downvotes your answer the default sort order of votes causes them to gain artificial ranking above yours (or equal depending on votes) which can make their answer look like the "best/first" answer. It's shady but I think it happens a fair bit.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, I very much agree.

Comment: "Why downvote an already accepted answer?" For the same reasons you would downvote any answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I'm not sure what that means really. The only time I down-vote an answer is when it's blatantly wrong.  Sometimes I don't at all.  Other users, myself included, will at least give the answerer a chance to fix it by leaving a comment, before getting trigger happy with the down arrow.

Comment: This question is moot now. Your answer was finally accepted. The original poster probably marked your answer as accepted the first time without testing it. Then, after the downvote, he started to doubt that your answer was correct. But then, he probably tested your answer, found it to be correct, and came back a third time to mark your answer as correct. This Stack Overflow process is not clean, but it seems to be good enough for its purpose. Even if the original poster had not come back to mark your answer as accepted, this problem is definitely not worth fretting over.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am willing to step up and speculate.  I would say that your answer was correct, but that it was less elegant then the other two answers provided. My guess is that the voters would have preferred that one of those was selected over your answer.

I would further speculate that the questioner saw the number of down votes your answer got and began to worry that your answer was not sufficient.

This of course was silly since the difference between your answer and their answers was one of taste primarily.  In addition, you completely answered the proffered question and for you to suffer a reputation assault as a result of you attempting to be helpful is well silly, but what can you do?

Comment: Thanks for this.  Your answer is down-right logical and I like it. :)

Comment: @RichardScriven It's likely you were downvoted for appearing to be whining about your Rep. People are people, and Rep votes don't always make sense. And now __I__ get downvoted for daring to mention Rep ; it's kind of like The Game - you lose just by thinking about it. Subliminally, I think some users innately dislike others who treat the site's gamified Rep as a kind of game despite it being a game mechanic because the questions are real ones and they feel as if their answered question for the purpose of  Rep has been made trivial or less important.

Answer (score 28):

Voters are not obligated to explain their votes, so there's no way to know.  Any other  analysis would be purely speculation.

Comment: Moreover, a selected answer does not necessarily mean good answer.

Comment: Although I am eager to know more about the "why", this is probably the best reason I'll get at this point.  I hope mandatory commenting/reasoning for downvotes get implemented at some point. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardScriven It never will be.  You can be confident of that.  It's been proposed many times, and a detailed analysis makes it quite clear that it would be a net destructive feature.

Comment: I think this is the point of `discussion` type questions on a meta site.  If you don't want to discuss them then fine but there is not point closing the conversation just because it does not interest you.

Comment: @RichardScriven You should have asked "why do you think my accepted answer was downvoted boohoo". In general, there is no reason an accepted answer should not be treated the same way as any other answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza I assume your comment was meant at face value so I will say, "do you really think that is fair?" It sounds rather the type of thing that would show up in a preschool classroom and really gets at the heart of what he is saying.  If it wasn't meant at face value but rather tongue in cheek then, "congrats!" You are right, that would have been a hilarious question title and certain to stimulate some real discussion rather than the terse responses his thought out and well worded question has generated.

Comment: @fsmart I think it is fair. The question pretends to be asking a general question (to which a good answer is "for the same reasons any answer would get downvoted. It being accepted makes no difference.") But it is really about a very specific situation where their answer got downvoted for no apparent reason. And that is completely open to speculation and uninteresting. It happens all the time, for various reasons.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the question at hand is not "Why did my accepted answer get downvoted?".  I'm not that stupid.  The question is "What would prompt someone to downvote an already accepted answer?"

Comment: @RichardScriven Come on, the question it completely focused on your experience, as is the chosen answer. You can claim otherwise, but you're not fooling anyone other than yourself.

Comment: Ehhh, ok juanchopanza, this sounds like the type of thing that shows up a lot on SE in various forms and regulars probably get very sick of seeing it as no amount of discussion will change the situation. My take away, don't complain about down votes. I am checking out.

Answer (score 5):

It is interesting to note that the alt text for the downvote arrow reads "this answer is not **useful**," yet there are those who are downvoting because the answer is not "good" as judged by some criteria of their own invention.  I submit they're doing it wrong.

Same goes with a lot of question downvotes.  People are creating their own criteria for what the "score" should be relative to other questions and answers and thinking that the downvote is an appropriate way to adjust things to their liking.

Seems to me that like comment upvotes, the answer "score" is supposed to be a count of usefulness.  But people are treating it like a cumulative overall quality ranking in a competition with the others.  It's not supposed to be.  You shouldn't cancel "useful" votes with "ehhh, clunky prose and lack of wit" downvotes.

Comment: How can an answer which is not good (or worse than others on the same question) be useful, unless it at least has some good points not in those other answers? At best, it does not waste so much time reading it as to warrant a downvote.

Comment: If someone suggests a different solution than the hordes think should be the standard, is it not useful?

Comment: I thought I listed that as an exception there :"unless it at least has some good points not in those other answers"? I would not downvote just because the answer does not present or at least mention my favorite way...

Comment: Now you're judging goodness separate from usefulness

Answer (score 2):

> What would prompt someone to downvote an already accepted answer?

I have downvoted [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151701/running-google-analytics-in-iframe) that only link to a site with an answer where the link doesn't work and the answer doesn't actually provide an answer without the link.  My thought is that the person who gave the answer will update it seeing the downvote may update the answer with content that helps and/or help others looking for the answer find the real answer faster (by comparing answer votes).

Comment: I will even flag accepted answers if they are link-only (sorry moderators).

Comment: (Yes I do that too, but that isn't what the OP asked).

Answer (score 2):

Just in-case your hidden agenda would be to block downvotes on the accepted answers, **no, it's bad idea!**. There should be **no immunity** against downvotes for accepted answers. Accepted answer is not always the best, not always even correct.

People often accept what they think should work, not what is actually working, not to mention any possible security and performance issues they're not aware of.

If you fill that your answer is correct, and probably it is, well, there's no difference between downvoting good answer and downvoting good accepted answer. Both are injust, but unfortunatelly happen. The downvoter may be convinced your answer is bad, insecure, inefficient etc. even if those are completely false assumptions. You can't forbid people having false assumptions (well, strictly speaking, you can, but the consequences are gloomy).