# How to handle accepted but wrong answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

I have found some answers, they are not correct, but accepted as correct answers.
How can we treat such answers.

Comment: I believe that StackOverflow is intended to enhance our knowldege,but at the same time some people giving answers to  some queries are not enhancing the knowledge but just giving the solutions to the problem(or say short cuts but not efficient way).As **these solutions make the OP's code run(the way he/seh wants),so they accept them as answers.** But there  are other correct and efficient ways by which the problem can be solved. I have seen this  happening a lot on StackOverflow.

Comment: Downvote, leave a comment, upvote the correct ones or add a better one.

Comment: Sometimes [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251606/why-downvote-an-already-accepted-answer) happens too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well here are things that you could do here:

1. Vote down the answer
2. Comment warnings why you think the answer is a mistake. (Author might edit it)
3. Give an alternative answer which you think is appropriate

Things you can't do

1. Edit the answer (Edit is for minor grammar, spelling or formatting problems only)
2. Ask someone to remove it as accepted answer (The inquirer of the question has full rights to accept an answer he/she sees fit, even if it is a mistake)

Comment: You can ask the OP to change the accepted answer. They might not listen, but there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Oh by ask someone I meant the moderators. But yes tnx for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 5):

There are many questions on SO that are *incorrect* but *accepted*. The simplest thing that can be done is to down-vote the answer and then leave a comment to the question (so that the OP finds out) as well as the answer (so that the answerer finds out) that the accepted answer is wrong. I've been on either side of this :P. If you know the correct answer, then you could answer the question yourself :)